# JSON parse and display url in textview

Tags: android, json

I need to parse and display url content in listview. I have parsed title,date, content,name  and image using lazyloading but now i need to parse url and display its content in listview.
But the problem here instead of diplaying url it is displaying image url. It is displaying like this http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/18/device20130202121840.png/ following is my json response(only few response included here) and parsing code

```
"posts": [
    {
        "id": 2954,
        "type": "ad_listing",
        "slug": "commander-retreat-for-sale",
        "url": "http://avoidserum/ads/commander-retreat-for-sale/",
        "status": "publish",
        "title": "Commander Retreat for sale",
        "title_plain": "Commander Retreat for sale",
        "content": "<p>Commander Retreat : Hebbal Lake<br />\n2 BHK<br />\nBuilt up: 1180sft<br />\n3rd floor<br />\nTotal G+3 floors<br />\nWest facing<br />\nFurnished<br />\nSale price Rs. 50lacs ( nego)<br />\nFor further details please call M/s. Farid Consultants @ 9844106901 /9880123548<br />\nEmail: manjula@faridconsultants.com</p>\n",
        "excerpt": "Commander Retreat : Hebbal Lake 2 BHK Built up: 1180sft 3rd floor Total G+3 floors West facing Furnished Sale price Rs. 50lacs ( nego) For further details please call M/s. Farid Consultants @ 9844106901 /9880123548 Email: manjula@faridconsultants.com",
        "date": "2013-02-01 05:09:58",
        "modified": "2013-02-01 05:09:58",
        "categories": [],
        "tags": [],
        "author": {
            "id": 344,
            "slug": "ruby",
            "name": "Ruby",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "nickname": "Ruby",
            "url": "",
            "description": ""
        },
        "comments": [],
        "attachments": [
            {
                "id": 2955,
                "url": "http://imageurl/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/785862.jpg",
                "slug": "commander-retreat-for-sale",
                "title": "Commander Retreat for sale",
                "description": "",
                "caption": "",
                "parent": 2954,
                "mime_type": "image/jpeg",

    },
   .....................
```

Parsing code

```
 static final String KEY_POSTS = "posts";
 static final String KEY_ID = "id";
 static final String KEY_SITEURL = "url";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
static final String KEY_CONTENT = "content";
static final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_ATTACHMENTS = "attachments";
static final String KEY_SLUG = "slug";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumbnail";
static final String KEY_IMAGES = "images";
static final String KEY_URL = "url";

final  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        // Creating JSON Parser instance
                final JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
                try {
                     posts = json.getJSONArray(KEY_POSTS);

        // looping through all song nodes <song>
                for(int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(KEY_ID);
                    String siteurl = c.getString(KEY_SITEURL);
                    String title = c.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                    String date = c.getString(KEY_DATE);
                    String content = c.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
                    // to remove all <P> </p> and <br /> and replace with ""
                     content = content.replace("<br />", "");
                     content = content.replace("<p>", "");
                     content = content.replace("</p>", "");

                    //authornumber is agin  JSON Object
                    JSONObject author = c.getJSONObject(KEY_AUTHOR);
                    String name = author.getString(KEY_NAME);

                    String url1 = null;
                    String slug1 = null;
                    try {
                    JSONArray atta = c.getJSONArray("attachments");
                    for(int j = 0; j < atta.length(); j++){
                        JSONObject d = atta.getJSONObject(j);

                        slug1 = d.getString(KEY_SLUG);

                        JSONObject images = d.getJSONObject(KEY_IMAGES);

                        JSONObject thumbnail = images.getJSONObject(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                        url1 = thumbnail.getString(KEY_URL);

                    }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }




            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, id);
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
            map.put(KEY_SITEURL, siteurl);
            map.put(KEY_DATE, date);
            map.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            map.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
            map.put(KEY_SLUG, slug1);
            map.put(KEY_URL, url1);


            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
                }   
                }catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    }



         final ListView  list=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

         // Getting adapter by passing json data ArrayList
            adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);    
             list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

LazyAdapter.java

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}



public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    TextView siteurl = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.siteurl);
    TextView date = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.date); // artist name
    TextView content = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.content);  // duration
    TextView name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name); 
    // duration
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song = data.get(position);


    ListView list;
    // Setting all values in listview
   title.setText(song.get(MainActivity.KEY_TITLE));
   siteurl.setText(song.get(MainActivity.KEY_SITEURL));
    date.setText(song.get(MainActivity.KEY_DATE));
    content.setText(song.get(MainActivity.KEY_CONTENT));
    name.setText(song.get(MainActivity.KEY_NAME));

   imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(MainActivity.KEY_URL), thumb_image);
    return vi;
}
```

}

ImageLoader.java

```
         public class ImageLoader {
    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new     WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService; 

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    final int stub_id = R.drawable.dollardesi;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        System.out.println("Image bitmap object from url*********$$$$$$$$"+bitmap);

        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
        {
          System.out.println("In the else where there is null bitmap>>>>>>>>>");
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u;
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if(bitmap!=null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }
```

}

Comment: *instead of diplaying url it is displaying image url* becuase you have image url that's why it's displaying image url in ListView then what is issue

Comment: If you want the `"url": "http://india.dollardesi.net/ads/commander-retreat-for-sale/",` Why are you calling a key: SITEURL?

Comment: I have given "url": "http://india.dollardesi.net/ads/commander-retreat-for-sale/", name as KEY_SITEURL just to make difference between image url and this link url for image url i have given KEY_URL @Gjordis

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K i have  "url": "india.dollardesi.net/ads/commander-retreat-for-sale/" also i need to display this but i am getting image url

Comment: @vyb : post  LazyAdapter adapter code also with question because problem is inside LazyAdapter instead of json parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting issue because both key is same for `KEY_SITEURL` and `KEY_URL` in `HashMap` so just change any one key to get it work as :

```
static final String KEY_URL_FOR_MAP = "url_site";   //use this for adding 
                                               //and retrivng value from Hashmap
static final String KEY_URL = "url";   // use this for getting url JsonObject
static final String KEY_SITEURL = "url";
```

now  use `KEY_URL_FOR_MAP` for adding url to `Hashmap` and to retrieve url form `HashMap`

Comment: I dint get from where will i get this  "url_site" @ρяσѕρєя K

Comment: @vyb : change `map.put(KEY_SITEURL, url1);` to `map.put(KEY_URL_FOR_MAP, url1);`

Comment: @vyb : and `siteurl.setText(song.get(MainActivity.KEY_SITEURL));` to `siteurl.setText(song.get(MainActivity.KEY_URL_FOR_MAP));`

Comment: @vyb : most welcome friend .  don't forget to up-votes answers if u will get help. Thanks so much

Comment: changing this siteurl.setText(song.get(MainActivity.KEY_SITEURL)); to siteurl.setText(song.get(MainActivity.KEY_URL_FOR_MAP)); giving the same old result. By changing only change map.put(KEY_SITEURL, url1); to map.put(KEY_URL_FOR_MAP, url1); gives the correct output @ ρяσѕρєя K Anyway thanks again i have upvoted :)